# Posting a status to Facebook API, Help :(

Tags: php, mysql, facebook, facebook-graph-api

In short, I want to use FB api for posting the status, in this scenario :

the user have to type some update (in my website) which will posted to db,
the user may check (post to fb) so that the update also appears in his FB profile.

for posting the update in my website I have a textarea in an HTML form which points the action to another php file (to write it in the DB)

Finally I wil I'll show you both files to be safe and give accurate answers

How to integrate both actions (posting to both FB and DB) , what should I do and where?

Thx

Comment: The answer is probably out of the scope of this question. You might have better luck if you research the facebook API and then ask a question after you get stuck. Essentially you'll need to register your application with facebook, use their PHP API to allow a user to grant your app permissions and return a valid session. Then you'll be able to use the API to do things like update statuses.

Comment: I have already registered my application sir. and I know how to define the connection between my page and FB. I just want some hints to go on.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Following the *new* [php-sdk](https://github.com/facebook/php-sdk/) workflow should be easily:

your page should contains the login button with the necessary JS and server-side script to hold the session just like the [`example.php`](https://github.com/facebook/php-sdk/blob/master/examples/example.php). One important note here is that you need to ask the user for the `publish_stream` permission so your login button should look like:

```
<fb:login-button perms="read_stream,publish_stream"></fb:login-button>
```

Now on refresh, you check that you have a valid session so you show the submission form, or the "facebook" checkbox...

After submission and in your action file, for example `post.php`:
You get the `$_POST['user_status']` validate it and submit it to your DB and then check for the facebook checkbox AND if you have a valid session:

```
require '../src/facebook.php';
$facebook = new Facebook(array(
  'appId' => 'APP_ID',
  'secret' => 'APP_SEC',
  'cookie' => true,
));
$session = $facebook->getSession();

if($session && isset($_POST['fb_checkbox'])) {
    $facebook->api('/me/feed', 'post', array('message'=>$_POST['user_status']));
}
```

More details on what you can post is available [here](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/post/).

This should give you an idea how to start. :-)

Answer (score 5):

The following code should help;

```
$facebook = new Facebook(array(
 'appId'  => FACEBOOK_APP_ID,
 'secret' => FACEBOOK_SECRET,
 'cookie' => false,
));
```

Enter Application settings

```
$facebook_url = $facebook->getLoginUrl(array(
 'next' => '',
 'cancel_url' => '',
 'req_perms' => 'email,publish_stream,status_update'
));
```

Use this url to authenticate the user, as it will grant permission to post status updates

```
$attachment =  array(
 'message' => '[Status message]',
 'name' => '[Post title]',
 'link' => '[Post image & title link]',
 'description' => '[Post description]',
 'picture'=> '[Post Thumbnail Location]'
);

$facebook->api('/me/feed', 'POST', $attachment);
```

This will post the contents of `$attachment` to the authenticated user's wall.